# In React and Material-UI how do I make my Grid items take up 100% of available horizontal space w/o wrapping to the next row?

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, material-ui, width

I'm using Material-UI in a React 16.10 application.  I want to display a table with an icon in the left column and then a label and address, stacked on top of each other in the right column.  I want the items in the right column to take up 100% of the available space.  So I have this class

```
fullWidth: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    width: "100%",
  },
```

(the background color was just so I could see what was going on).  I created this table ...

```
          <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="top" spacing={1} className={classes.fullWidth}>
            <Grid item>
              <LocationOnIcon />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="center">
                <Grid item className={classes.fullWidth} style={{backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>
                  <TextField
                    className={`${classes.rootInput} ${classes.input}`}
                    id="pickupLocationLabel"
                    value={values.pickUpLocationLabel}
                    placeholder="Label"
                    variant="outlined"
                    disabled={false}
                    onChange={handleChangePickUpLocationLabel}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item className={classes.fullWidth}>
                  <AddressInput
                    className={classes.textField}
                    placeholder={values.pickUpLocation?.address}
                    stage={values.pickUpLocation}
                    setStage={handleChangeLocation.bind(null, "pickUpLocation")}
                    setLocation={handleChangeLocation}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
```

However, the items didn't take up 100% of the available width ...

[image]

When I added the fullWidth class to the parent container,

```
          <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="top" spacing={1} className={classes.fullWidth}>
            <Grid item>
              <LocationOnIcon />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item className={classes.fullWidth}>
              <Grid container direction="column" alignItems="center">
                <Grid item className={classes.fullWidth} style={{backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>
                  <TextField
                    className={`${classes.rootInput} ${classes.input}`}
                    id="pickupLocationLabel"
                    value={values.pickUpLocationLabel}
                    placeholder="Label"
                    variant="outlined"
                    disabled={false}
                    onChange={handleChangePickUpLocationLabel}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item className={classes.fullWidth}>
                  <AddressInput
                    className={classes.textField}
                    placeholder={values.pickUpLocation?.address}
                    stage={values.pickUpLocation}
                    setStage={handleChangeLocation.bind(null, "pickUpLocation")}
                    setLocation={handleChangeLocation}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
```

Then the items no longer lined up alongside the icon.

[image: ct and]
How do I adjust things to that they take up 100% of the available width without wrapping to the next row?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `classes.fullWidth` for the sizing of the `Grid items`? Material-UI offers a `Bootstrap` type system that allows you to size items in the Grid depending on the size of the screen. Check out the `Grid API` [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#main-content).

Try ditching `classes.fullWidth` and replacing it with `xs=12` and see if that does the trick and gets the element to take up the full width.

There is also a `wrap/nowrap` prop you can pass to the Grid item to deal with wrapping.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work sometimes and I can't seem to figure out why. I end up having to replace xs={12} with classes.fullWidth.